# Expandable listview cannot expand properly at 4th level

Tags: android

i am working on 4 level expandable list view it is everything fine till 3rd level but when i programetically make a expandable list view it is not expand properly to the whole screen.

Here is my code:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
public static final int FIRST_LEVEL_COUNT = 1;
public static final int SECOND_LEVEL_COUNT = 2;
public static final int THIRD_LEVEL_COUNT = 3;
public static final int FORTH_LEVEL_COUNT = 4;
private ExpandableListView expandableListView;



@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    expandableListView = (ExpandableListView) findViewById(R.id.mainList);
    expandableListView.setAdapter(new ParentLevel(this));

}

public class ParentLevel extends BaseExpandableListAdapter {

    private Context context;

    public ParentLevel(Context context) {
        this.context = context;
    }

    @Override
    public Object getChild(int arg0, int arg1) {
        return arg1;
    }

    @Override
    public long getChildId(int groupPosition, int childPosition) {
        return childPosition;
    }

    @Override
    public View getChildView(int groupPosition, int childPosition, boolean isLastChild, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        SecondLevelExpandableListView secondLevelELV = new SecondLevelExpandableListView(MainActivity.this);
        secondLevelELV.setAdapter(new SecondLevelAdapter(context));
        secondLevelELV.setGroupIndicator(null);
        return secondLevelELV;
    }

    @Override
    public int getChildrenCount(int groupPosition) {
        return SECOND_LEVEL_COUNT;
    }

    @Override
    public Object getGroup(int groupPosition) {
        return groupPosition;
    }

    @Override
    public int getGroupCount() {
        return FIRST_LEVEL_COUNT;
    }

    @Override
    public long getGroupId(int groupPosition) {
        return groupPosition;
    }

    @Override
    public View getGroupView(int groupPosition, boolean isExpanded, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        if (convertView == null) {
            LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.row_first, null);
            TextView text = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.eventsListEventRowText);
            text.setText("FIRST LEVEL");

        }
        return convertView;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean hasStableIds() {
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isChildSelectable(int groupPosition, int childPosition) {
        return true;
    }
}

public class SecondLevelExpandableListView extends ExpandableListView {

    public SecondLevelExpandableListView(Context context) {
        super(context);
    }

    protected void onMeasure(int widthMeasureSpec, int heightMeasureSpec) {
        //999999 is a size in pixels. ExpandableListView requires a maximum height in order to do measurement calculations.
        heightMeasureSpec = MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(1500, MeasureSpec.AT_MOST);
        super.onMeasure(widthMeasureSpec, heightMeasureSpec);
    }
}

public class ThirdLevelExpandableListView extends ExpandableListView  {



    public ThirdLevelExpandableListView(Context context) {
        super(context);
    }

    protected void onMeasure(int widthMeasureSpec, int heightMeasureSpec) {
        //999999 is a size in pixels. ExpandableListView requires a maximum height in order to do measurement calculations.
        heightMeasureSpec = MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(500 , MeasureSpec.AT_MOST);
        super.onMeasure(widthMeasureSpec, heightMeasureSpec);
    }
}

public class SecondLevelAdapter extends BaseExpandableListAdapter {

    private Context context;

    public SecondLevelAdapter(Context context) {
        this.context = context;
    }

    @Override
    public Object getGroup(int groupPosition) {
        return groupPosition;
    }

    @Override
    public int getGroupCount() {
        return 1;
    }

    @Override
    public long getGroupId(int groupPosition) {
        return groupPosition;
    }

    @Override
    public View getGroupView(int groupPosition, boolean isExpanded, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        if (convertView == null) {
            LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.row_third, null);
            TextView text = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.eventsListEventRowText);
            text.setText("SECOND LEVEL");
        }
        return convertView;
    }

    @Override
    public Object getChild(int groupPosition, int childPosition) {
        return childPosition;
    }

    @Override
    public long getChildId(int groupPosition, int childPosition) {
        return childPosition;
    }

    @Override
    public View getChildView(int groupPosition, int childPosition, boolean isLastChild, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        if (convertView == null) {
           /* LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.row_second, null);
            TextView text = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.eventsListEventRowText);
            text.setText("THIRD LEVEL");*/
            ThirdLevelExpandableListView thirdlevelELV= new ThirdLevelExpandableListView(MainActivity.this);
           /* ExpandableListView thirdlevelELV=new ExpandableListView(MainActivity.this);
            LinearLayout.LayoutParams layoutParams=new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT);
            thirdlevelELV.setLayoutParams(layoutParams);*/
            thirdlevelELV.setAdapter(new ThirdLevelAdapter(context));
            thirdlevelELV.setGroupIndicator(null);
            return thirdlevelELV;
        }

        return convertView;
    }

    @Override
    public int getChildrenCount(int groupPosition) {
        return THIRD_LEVEL_COUNT;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean hasStableIds() {
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isChildSelectable(int groupPosition, int childPosition) {
        return true;
    }
}
public class ThirdLevelAdapter extends BaseExpandableListAdapter {

    private Context context;

    public ThirdLevelAdapter(Context context) {
        this.context = context;
    }

    @Override
    public Object getGroup(int groupPosition) {
        return groupPosition;
    }

    @Override
    public int getGroupCount() {
        return THIRD_LEVEL_COUNT;
    }

    @Override
    public long getGroupId(int groupPosition) {
        return groupPosition;
    }

    @Override
    public View getGroupView(int groupPosition, boolean isExpanded, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        if (convertView == null) {
            LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.row_third, null);
            TextView text = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.eventsListEventRowText);
            text.setText("THIRD LEVEL");
        }
        return convertView;
    }

    @Override
    public Object getChild(int groupPosition, int childPosition) {
        return childPosition;
    }

    @Override
    public long getChildId(int groupPosition, int childPosition) {
        return childPosition;
    }

    @Override
    public View getChildView(int groupPosition, int childPosition, boolean isLastChild, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        if (convertView == null) {
            LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.row_forth, null);
            TextView text = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.eventsListEventRowText);
            text.setText("FORTH LEVEL");
        }
        return convertView;
    }

    @Override
    public int getChildrenCount(int groupPosition) {
        return FORTH_LEVEL_COUNT;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean hasStableIds() {
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isChildSelectable(int groupPosition, int childPosition) {
        return true;
    }
}
```

}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got the answer and i am using treeeview instead of expandable recyclarview. To implement it just do several steps...

```
import 'com.github.bmelnychuk:atv:1.2.+'
```

or you get the example from `https://github.com/bmelnychuk/AndroidTreeView` here.

Thanks